# Get count of associations in many to many from inverse object in Doctrine, without inverse mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

In Doctrine DQL, I am trying to get the count from a many-to-many association without the entity I am working with having an inverse mapping.

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a AS attribute')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(p) AS num_products')
    ->from('VendorAttributeBundle:Attribute', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('VendorProductBundle:Product', 'p', 'WITH', 'a MEMBER OF p.attributes')
    ->groupBy('a.id');
```

The above runs but returns `0` for the `num_products` field.

Comment: I performed your query on biderectional many-to-many entities and it works well. Try to find error in your mapping. See my example https://gist.github.com/Infernosquad/cc6237e7c782892e70ba33dd36976234

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just went ahead and created the inverse mapping. I couldn't get it work without.

---

**For reference:**

In the `Attribute` Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Vendor\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="attributes")
 */
private $products;
```

In the `Product` Entity:

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Vendor\AttributeBundle\Entity\Attribute", inversedBy="products")
 */
private $attributes;
```

Then the following worked:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('a AS attribute')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(p) AS num_products')
    ->from('VendorAttributeBundle:Attribute', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('VendorProductBundle:Product', 'p')
    ->groupBy('a.id');
```